# Understanding paste0 in R

Tags: r

```
1.for(sublen in len:1) {
2.        for(inlen in 0:sublen) {
3.      pat <- paste0("((.{", sublen-inlen, "})(.)(.{", inlen, "}))", reps("(\\2.\\4)", th-1))
4.            r <- regexpr(pat, string, perl = TRUE)
```

So, I have this snippet of code, where the value of len is 3 and th = 3 as well. Now, reps is a function I made which is something like,

```
5.s <- function(s, n) paste(rep(s, n), collapse = "")
```

I am trying to understand what the the lines 1-4 actually do? I know, that in line 5, there is a function which basically repeats s n times. What I really want to know, is, what is happening in line 3. I tried experimenting with this command in R.

```
paste0("(  ( .{", 3-0, "} ) (.) ( .{", 0, "} )  )",  rep("(\\2.\\4)", 3-1) )
```

with the output, but then how does it actually matches the pattern by regexpr command in line 4?

```
[1] "(  ( .{3} ) (.) ( .{0} )  )(\\2.\\4)" "(  ( .{3} ) (.) ( .{0} )  )(\\2.\\4)"
```

Edit: Example of string : 110110111
What it would basically return after adding a few more lines of code ( comparing if greater than 0 ) a pattern which will be "110", although there is some disturbance involved at the last character and pattern is not perfect. But how is it actually working with the paste0 command?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Do you not know how the regular expression works? It's hard to say what it's doing with out an example `string` value to see what it's matching against. All `paste0` does is concatenate string values.

Comment: Yes, exactly. All it does is concatenate values. But then, what does \\2 and \\4 represent?
PS: Example coming right now. :)

Comment: That is part of the syntax of the regular expression. It respectively means the contents of the second and fourth captured matches. It has nothing to do with `paste0`.

Comment: And then what is sublen doing and inlen doing. I ran the command with sublen initial value as 3 and inlen as 0. I got this, [1] "((.{3})(.)(.{0}))(\\2.\\4)(\\2.\\4)" ---- How will this lead to a match in the original string? And can you please explain your comment in a seperate answer with an example. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with `paste0` really. This code just uses `paste0` to build a regular expression. With len and th=3, It will produce the following patterns (I printed these with `cat` to remove the noisy slash escaping R uses when printing character to the console)

```
((.{3})(.)(.{0}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{2})(.)(.{1}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{1})(.)(.{2}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{0})(.)(.{3}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{2})(.)(.{0}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{1})(.)(.{1}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{0})(.)(.{2}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{1})(.)(.{0}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{0})(.)(.{1}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
```

The parentheses capture parts of a string. The `.` means any charater. The `{n}` values look for the previous character repeated `n` times. And `\n` matches the contents of `n-th` capture group.

The second pattern in the list

```
((.{2})(.)(.{1}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
```

looks for strings in the form

```
AAxBAAyBAAzB
```

where `x`, `y` and `z` can be anything and all `A` values must match and all `B` values must match. You can test this patter [here](http://regex101.com/r/sI6uS4)

So your example pattern of

```
110110111
```

will be matched by both

```
((.{2})(.)(.{0}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
((.{0})(.)(.{1}))(\2.\4)(\2.\4)
```

I strongly recommend you find some introduction to regular expressions online somewhere and read-up if you are really interested in understanding the code.